# MongoDB - If not empty array in document sum like single

Tags: mongodb

I have that query in MongoDB:

```
db.emailGroup.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "link",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "emailGroupId",
    "as": "link"    
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "link": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$link",
        "as": "l",
        "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$l.originalLink", "" ] }    
      }
    },
    "deliveredEmails": {
      "$sum": {
        "$map": {
          "input": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$link",
              "as": "l",
              "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$l.originalLink", "" ] }
            }
          },
          "as": "l",
          "in": { "$size": { "$ifNull": [ "$$l.linkHistory", [] ] } }
        }     
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$link" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$partId",
    "deliveredEmails": { "$sum": "$deliveredEmails" }
  }}
])
```

Sample documents:

emailGroup:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("594a6c47f51e075db713ccb6"),
    "partId" : "f56c7c71eb14a20e6129a667872f9c4f",
}
```

link:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("594b96d6f51e075db67c44c9"),
    "originalLink" : "",
    "emailGroupId" : ObjectId("594a6c47f51e075db713ccb6"),
    "linkHistory" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("594b96f5f51e075db713ccdf"),
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("594b971bf51e075db67c44ca"),
        }
    ]
}
```

In this situation I sum all records in linkHistory for partId group. I want sum single occurence. For example - if linkHistory not empty add 1 to sum, otherwise 0.

Current result:

```
{
    "_id" : "f56c7c71eb14a20e6129a667872f9c4f",
    "deliveredEmails" : 2
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
    "_id" : "f56c7c71eb14a20e6129a667872f9c4f",
    "deliveredEmails" : 1
}
```

Extra question: how can I sum occurrence emailGroup._id in this situation? I want add new field like "deliveredEmails" with this sum.

Expected result:

```
{
    "_id" : "f56c7c71eb14a20e6129a667872f9c4f",
    "deliveredEmails" : 1,
    "numberOfEmails" : 1
}
```

Comment: You really need to realize here the format is "one question". And then please ask it clearly. How about instead you show some documents and also show the output you expect to get from those documents.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Post was edit.

Comment: Your extra question is unclear. You don't sum `_ids`. For the first part, it looks like you can change the map's in expression to `"in": { "$cond": [{$eq:[{ "$ifNull": [ "$$l.linkHistory", [] ] }, []], 0, 1] } }`

Comment: Sorry, my english is not good. I want return how much emailGroup._id is in partId and add this information to new field. I checked your changes in my query and return error "Unexpected token ,",

Comment: Np. Sorry, closing braces were placed incorrectly. Try this `"in": { "$cond": [{$eq:[{ "$ifNull": [ "$$l.linkHistory", [] ] }, []]}, 0, 1] }`. For the extra question part, add `"numberOfEmails": { "$sum": 1 }` in your group stage.

Comment: It's work, thank you.